# How to make the UIImage edges softer?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a UIImage with a UIVisualEffectView on top of it. I want to make the edges softer to give it a shadow effect.

[image]

I tried playing around with `maskToBounds` but it doesn't make a difference.

```
let weekndImage = UIImage(named: "weeknd.jpg")
let weekndIV = UIImageView(image: weekndImage)
weekndIV.frame.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)

let blur = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blur)


blurView.frame = weekndIV.bounds

weekndIV.addSubview(blurView)

weekndIV.layer.cornerRadius = 10
weekndIV.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: I don't see the "shadow" in your illustration. And softening of _edges_ would be done with a _mask_, not a blur.

Answer (score 0):

move these two lines after setting the blurView frame and before adding blurView to weekndIV view

```
weekndIV.layer.cornerRadius = 10
weekndIV.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have a shadow effect on your view. For that you can access `shadowOpacity` and `shadowRadius` from `layer` of your view

For example in **Swift 2**:

```
class MyView : UIView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0)
    }
}
```